# Android: ImageView, keep the aspect ratio

Tags: android, image

Lets say I have image test.png with size h:40px w:80px

And I have ImageView, with height: 80px.

How to set image to this ImageView, so that image could fit ImageView but proportionally ?

So I need image to fit height, that mean it should become 80px height,
and fit width as much as needed for image to be proportional, so width should become 160px

I know I can just cut a bigger image, its not a solution for me.

Tried:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

but its not adjust width.

Comment: in this case of expanding beyond original size will cause the image to become pixelated (blurry).  I would just center the image

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ImageView` (or other `View`) that you want to have a width of `fill_parent` and a height scaled proportionately:

Add these two attributes to your `ImageView`:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

And set the `ImageView` width to `fill_parent` and height to `wrap_content`.

See [`android:adjustViewBounds`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds).

Comment: I need image to be height 80px. Your solution crop my image. I need all image to be visible and proportional

Answer (score 1):

`fitXY` does not keep the aspect radio. You have to use one from `CENTER_CROP` and `CENTER_INSIDE`. From the doc

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that
>   both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or
>   larger than the corresponding dimension of the view

Comment: It crops my image, not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use the ‘android:src’ instead of background